# How to create an image grid/mortar with dynamic sizing while keeping images aspect ratio, without cropping?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to dynamically place images in a grid/mortar view while keeping their original aspect ratio. Basically, I am trying to achieve a solution similar to that of Adobe Lightroom.

[image: adobe lightroom cc]

I originally tried to achieve this by fixing the height, dynamically changing the cell width based on the remaining row space and the image scale. However, because I am using `scaleAspectFit` the image is scaled, meaning that sometimes some images are cropped.

My guess is that I will have to dynamically play with the height as well, but I do not see how.

The code I am using to do the normalization process is:

```
var i = 0
while i < sizes.count {
    var maxWidth = collectionViewWidth // the width of the UICollectionView
    var rowWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var j = i
    while rowWidth < maxWidth, j < sizes.count {
        let belowThreshold = sizes[j].width < (maxWidth - rowWidth) * 1.30
        let remainsEnough = (maxWidth - rowWidth) / maxWidth > 0.3 && belowThreshold
        if belowThreshold || remainsEnough {
            rowWidth += sizes[j].width
            j += 1
        } else { break }
    }

    let spacing = CGFloat((j - i - 1) * 2)
    maxWidth -= spacing
    var newRowWidth: CGFloat = 0
    for l in i..<j {
        let x = (sizes[l].width * maxWidth) / rowWidth
        sizes[l].width = x.rounded(to: 3)
        newRowWidth += sizes[l].width
    }

    if newRowWidth >= maxWidth {
        let width = sizes[j-1].width - (newRowWidth - maxWidth).rounded(to: 3)
        sizes[j-1].width = width.rounded(to: 3)
    }

    i = j
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's a GitHub URL to a sample project with what I currently have: https://github.com/abrahamduran/ios-mortar-view

Comment: If you want to keep the aspect ratio AND the height the same AND the spacing constant... then you pretty much can’t. Something has to break. Do you want consistent spacing between them? Or do you want different heights in the same row?

Comment: The best approach to something like this is to go into something like Sketch and try it out. See what happens when you try to do it manually and see what constraints you need to apply in order to make this work. Then once you have an idea of what it will look like... start to develop it in code.

Comment: I see. I've been using the Lightroom app for quite a while; I think what they do is that they pick an individual height per row. Some rows are taller than others, but all the cells in that row have the same height.

Comment: I propose you to use `.scaleAspectFill` you will not notice cut edges on such small images. And please, do not use such names as `i`, `j`, `z` and values as `2`, `3`.

Comment: Can you upload sample project, I will try to fix it for you.

Comment: Sure @TimurBernikovich, thank you so much!
I'm creating the project, and I will upload later today to GitHub.
Regarding the variables names, my bad, I just used names usually see on array's indices, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @TimurBernikovich here's the GitHub url for the project: https://github.com/abrahamduran/ios-mortar-view

Comment: Could you use a 3rd party control? If so, something like: https://github.com/almas73/ImageGrid

Comment: Do you know the image size before rendering/downloading the image?

Comment: simply use a custom flow layout for your collection view, check https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: I've got a layout class that does this. I've dug it out, but it's a few Swift versions old! I'm going to try to upgrade and paste as an answer. There's a guide to the maths involved [here](https://medium.com/swlh/in-search-of-the-perfect-image-gallery-34f46f7615a1).

Comment: @AbrahamDurán I posted custom layout for your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote starting layout for you. You should verify all the code I posted ofc. Use custom layout like this:

```
let layout = CustomLayout()
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

...
// Delegate

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return images[indexPath.row].size
}
```

Code for **custom layout**.

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
}

class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var preferredHeight: CGFloat = 100 {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    fileprivate var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        cache.removeAll()
        guard let collectionView = collectionView,
            let delegate = collectionView.delegate as? CustomLayoutDelegate else {
            return
        }

        var sizes: [IndexPath: CGSize] = [:]

        let maxRowWidth = collectionView.frame.width - (collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right)

        var offsetY: CGFloat = 0
        var rowIndexes: [IndexPath] = []
        var rowWidth: CGFloat = 0
        let spacing = minimumInteritemSpacing

        let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let size = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            sizes[indexPath] = size

            let aspectRatio = size.width / size.height
            let preferredWidth = preferredHeight * aspectRatio
            rowWidth += preferredWidth
            rowIndexes.append(indexPath)

            if rowIndexes.count > 1 {
                // Check if we fit row width.
                let rowWidthWithSpacing = rowWidth + CGFloat(rowIndexes.count - 1) * spacing
                if rowWidthWithSpacing > maxRowWidth {
                    let previousRowWidthWithSpacing = rowWidthWithSpacing - spacing - preferredWidth
                    let diff = abs(maxRowWidth - rowWidthWithSpacing)
                    let previousDiff = abs(maxRowWidth - previousRowWidthWithSpacing)

                    let scale: CGFloat
                    let finalRowIndexPaths: [IndexPath]

                    if previousDiff < diff {
                        rowWidth -= preferredWidth
                        rowIndexes.removeLast()
                        finalRowIndexPaths = rowIndexes
                        scale = maxRowWidth / rowWidth
                        rowWidth = preferredWidth
                        rowIndexes = [indexPath]
                    } else {
                        finalRowIndexPaths = rowIndexes
                        scale = maxRowWidth / rowWidth
                        rowWidth = 0
                        rowIndexes = []
                    }

                    let finalHeight = preferredHeight * scale
                    var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
                    finalRowIndexPaths.forEach {
                        let size = sizes[$0]!
                        let scale = finalHeight / size.height
                        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: $0)
                        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: offsetX, y: offsetY, width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale).integral
                        offsetX = attributes.frame.maxX + spacing
                        cache.append(attributes)
                    }
                    offsetY = (cache.last?.frame.maxY ?? 0) + minimumLineSpacing
                }
            }

            if numberOfItems == item + 1 && !rowIndexes.isEmpty {
                let finalHeight = preferredHeight
                var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
                rowIndexes.forEach {
                    let size = sizes[$0]!
                    let scale = finalHeight / size.height
                    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: $0)
                    attributes.frame = CGRect(x: offsetX, y: offsetY, width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale).integral
                    offsetX = attributes.frame.maxX + spacing
                    cache.append(attributes)
                }
                offsetY = (cache.last?.frame.maxY ?? 0) + minimumLineSpacing
            }

            contentSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cache.last?.frame.maxY ?? 0)
        }
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }

}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much. It seems to me you really understand `UiCollectionView` Timur, do you mind recommending me some reading that could help me to get a better knowledge about it?

Comment: @AbrahamDuran just open RW's tutorials about UICollectionView and read them all.